# Why does a toolbar on a keyboard disappear when I use .fullScreenCover?

Tags: swiftui, navigation, keyboard, toolbar

I have an app for counting money from different events, so on the counting view there are TextEdits for all the different denominations. I had a pair of buttons above the keyboard place with this modifier to move focus to the next or previous denomination:

```
 .toolbar {ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
```

I was using NavigationStack for navigation, and the keyboard buttons were working. But when I extended the new NavigationStack/NavigationLink/navigationDestination throughout the app, it started looping, calling the View initialisers endlessly. So I switched to .fullScreenCover, except in the root View, a list of all the events, and the looping stopped. But, now the keyboard toolbar has stopped appearing.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: have you tried using `.toolbar { ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {...} }` instead of 
`.toolbar ( .toolbar {ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {...`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed it

Comment: Did you ever sort this?  I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, but annoying. I just put NavigationStack around the body components. Here is the current code of var body, which seems to work. All I did was add NavigationStack, and voilà the accessory view came back, and worked.

Note: mod is a function I wrote

```
  var body: some View {
    let totals = data.calcTotals()
    return NavigationStack {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(CoinNote.allCases.reversed(), id: \.self) { cn in  // Notes then coins
                ForEach(data.cashCountRows.filter( { $0.nc.coinNote == cn } )) { cashCountRow in
                    cashCountRow
                        .focused($focusIndex, equals: cashCountRow.index)
                        .frame(height: data.calcNcSize.height)
                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                        .background(focusIndex == cashCountRow.index ? Color.gray.opacity(0.15) : Color.clear)
                }
                TotalRow(data: data, title: cn.name, total: totals[cn])
                    .padding(.bottom)
            }// ForEach
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Done") { focusIndex = nil }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Prev") { focusIndex = ((focusIndex ?? 0) - 1).mod(data.cashCountRows.count) }
                    Button("Next") { focusIndex = ((focusIndex ?? 0) + 1).mod(data.cashCountRows.count) }
                }
            }// toolbar
        }// ScrollView
    }// NavigationStack
}// body
```

Note: mod is a function I wrote:

```
extension Int {
  func mod(_ divisor: Int) -> Int {
    let remainder = self % divisor
    return remainder >= 0 ? remainder : remainder + divisor
  }
}// extension Int
```